# Keyboard Tester Web Application in Vue 3 + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm working on keyboard testing web application. As a mechanical keyboard enthusiast, I need to test that all the keys on my keyboard work whenever I build one, or change the firmware for one. Eventually, I'd also like to implement some typing tests that are similar to [MonkeyType](https://monkeytype.com). This isn't a particularly new problem that's unsolved, but I thought it was a good chance to learn some Vue and TypeScript.

So far the codebase is only 3 files (that I've added on top of whatever Vue generates), but I have some questions. Full codebase is on [GitHub](https://github.com/hahuang65/type-test) if you'd like to run it

I'm brand new to Vue and TypeScript, so the things I'd like to know are:

- Am I doing things idiomatically?
- Am I sending events from `Keyboard` to `Key` in a way that makes sense?

  - This is my biggest question. Coming from other OOP languages, it made sense to make `Key` it's own component, but I feel like in Vue, there are going to be communication difficulties between `Keyboard` and `Key`. It's hard to decide where the state information (such as key position, not implemented yet) should go.
- Is there a better way to structure my components, given that I may also need to add more attributes to `Key` (things such as location on a keyboard grid, size of the button, etc)?
- When should I be using `setup()` vs `data()` or `created()` or `mounted()` etc.

  - It's quite confusing all the different things I've read only for using `const state = reactive({...})` and `...toRefs(state)` vs individual `ref`s vs just using `data()` etc.
- If I'm using TypeScript, should I still be using vanilla Javascript functions like `Object.fromEntries()`?

The 3 files of interest are the following:

`src/App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ state.appName }}</h1>
  <Keyboard />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from 'vue';
import Keyboard from "@/components/Keyboard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: { Keyboard },
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      appName: "Type Test"
    })

    return { state }
  }
});
</script>

<style>
  /* Used by Equal */
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined");
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700;900&display=swap");
</style>
```

`src/components/Keyboard.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div v-on:keyup="keyPressed" class="keyboard" tabindex="0">
    <!-- tabindex is set to make the div focus-able, which is required to respond to keypress events -->
    <Key v-for="(data, name) in state.keys" :key="name" :name="name" :pressed="data.pressed"/>
  </div>
  <it-button @click="resetKeys" type="danger">Reset</it-button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from 'vue';
import Key from '@/components/Key.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Keyboard",
  components: { Key },
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      keys: Object.fromEntries(
        [
          "q",
          "w",
          "e",
          "r",
          "t",
          "y",
          "u",
          "i",
          "o",
          "p",
          "[",
          "]",
          "\\",
          "a",
          "s",
          "d",
          "f",
          "g",
          "h",
          "j",
          "k",
          "l",
          ";",
          "'",
          "Enter",
          "Shift",
          "z",
          "x",
          "c",
          "v",
          "b",
          "n",
          "m",
          ",",
          ".",
          "/"
        ].map(name => [name, { pressed: false }])
      )
    })

    return { state }
  },
  methods: {
    keyPressed(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      console.log("Pressed: " +  event.key);
      console.log("Code: " +  event.key);
      console.log("Location: " + event.location);
      if (this.state.keys[event.key]) {
        this.state.keys[event.key]['pressed'] = true;
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    resetKeys() {
      let keys = Object.keys(this.state.keys)
      for (let key of keys) {
        this.state.keys[key]['pressed'] = false;
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

`src/components/Key.vue`:

```
<template>
  <it-button class="key" :type="pressed ? 'primary' : ''">
    {{ name }}
  </it-button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Key",
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    pressed: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.key {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1px;
}

.key.pressed {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
</style>
```